# how to edit a particular row in material-ui table?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am working on a react app with material-ui v4. I am trying to create an editable table, where on click of edit in a row, that particular row only should change to editable text field where user can modify values and save/discard changes. I tried following way but unable to change the property. I explored some SO Q&A but none is working for me.

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-stallman-4bo4f3?file=/src/Table.js

Comment: is it just me or is there a problem with the sandbox?