# How to return the old values on click of discard (close) icon while editing a material-ui table record?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

On top of [how to edit a particular row in material-ui table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71812542/how-to-edit-a-particular-row-in-material-ui-table/71812847?noredirect=1#comment126911818_71812847), whenever I am clicking on the X icon while editing a row, the changes still reflecting in the table. Is there any way to overcome it? The edited record should only save on check (_/) icon. I am fully blank on this now.

Playground: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-editable-tables-wsp0c?file=/package.json:0-677

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `onToggleEditMode` method. You are preserving the previous value fine during the `onChange` handler, and you are replacing the temporary value with the previous one during the `onRevert` handler properly. However, in that `onRevert` handler, you update the rows state with `setRows` and then call the `onToggleEditMode` function directly after, which still references the stale rows state object.

```
const onToggleEditMode = id => {
  setRows(state => {
    return rows.map(row => {
      if (row.id === id) {
        return { ...row, isEditMode: !row.isEditMode };
      }
      return row;
    });
  });
};
```

You need to use that `state` parameter on the second line so that you do not override the new value you just saved and create a race condition. I updated the method to the following, (I also cleaned up the row map method) and it worked in the sandbox:

```
const onToggleEditMode = (id) => {
  setRows((state) =>
    state.map((row) => ({
      ...row,
      isEditMode: row.id === id ? !row.isEditMode : row.isEditMode
    }))
  );
}
```

Comment: Actually this is also not working. On discarding, the first values are reflecting

Answer (score -1):

The example you provided shows that onChange() overrides the rows:

```
setRows(newRows);
```

My suggestion would be to create a draft copy of the edited row (since only one can be edited at the same time). Then overwrite the actual data with the draft if you click "approve" otherwise do nothing.
The behavior you describe is really just the custom logic in the code, there is nothing MUI-specific about it.
You will best learn how to do it if you do it on your own. I can check your example though.